# When many for loops are used in Javascript, output is undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

As shown at https://jsfiddle.net/LBMF_1/gacLzLnn/, I have code that ostensibly generates all the possible permutations of 8 digits, using for loops within for loops.(*At end of question*) My code seems to be correct in syntax, as both JSHint and the in-chrome console are free of errors. Is this my error, or is this a common problem caused by JS? *It's probably the former as it seems that this should work*
Bonus Points:
What other ways could be used to avoid the nested for loops?
You don't know how much I am thankful for any help.
Also, what is up with Stack Overflow and new paragraphs?
The code is here, and it appears to me that when run should stick a really long list of numbers in the console, but instead lots of "undefined"'s appear.

```
var generator = function() {
  listofavailable = listofavailablereset;
  fullarray = [];


  for (i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
    numgen = "";
    inum = listofavailable[i];
    listofavailable.splice(i, 1);
    numgen = inum;
    for (v = 6; v > 0; v--) {
      vnum = listofavailable[v];
      listofavailable.splice(v, 1);
      numgen = numgen.concat(vnum);
      console.log(numgen);
      for (c = 5; c > 0; c--) {
        cnum = listofavailable[c];
        listofavailable.splice(c, 1);
        numgen = numgen.concat(cnum);
        for (g = 4; g > 0; g--) {
          gnum = listofavailable[g];
          listofavailable.splice(g, 1);
          numgen = numgen.concat(gnum);
          for (k = 3; k > 0; k--) {
            knum = listofavailable[k];
            listofavailable.splice(k, 1);
            numgen = numgen.concat(knum);
            for (b = 2; b > 0; b--) {
              bnum = listofavailable[b];
              listofavailable.splice(b, 1);
              numgen = numgen.concat(bnum);
              for (j = 1; j > 0; j--) {
                jnum = listofavailable[j];
                listofavailable.splice(j, 1);
                numgen = numgen.concat(jnum);
                fullarray = fullarray + numgen;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: Have you considered refactoring to anything more readable?

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with `for` loops. The problem is that `numgen` is `undefined` at some point when you're trying to `.concat()` to it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript for a better way to generate permutations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified implementation based on your fiddle.
Note that the digits '0' and '5' are missing from your example, I'm not sure if this is intended.

```
var listofavailable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
var fullarray;

var generator = function() {
  fullarray = [];
  var numgen;
  // first digit
  for (var a = 7; a >= 0; a--) {
    var anum = listofavailable[a];
    listofavailable.splice(a, 1);
    numgen = anum;
    // second digit
    for (var i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
      var inum = listofavailable[i];
      listofavailable.splice(i, 1);
      numgen = numgen.concat(inum);
      // third digit
      for (var v = 5; v >= 0; v--) {
        var vnum = listofavailable[v];
        listofavailable.splice(v, 1);
        numgen = numgen.concat(vnum);
        // fourth digit
        for (var c = 4; c >= 0; c--) {
          var cnum = listofavailable[c];
          listofavailable.splice(c, 1);
          numgen = numgen.concat(cnum);
          // fifth digit
          for (var g = 3; g >= 0; g--) {
            var gnum = listofavailable[g];
            listofavailable.splice(g, 1);
            numgen = numgen.concat(gnum);
            // sixth digit
            for (var k = 2; k >= 0; k--) {
              var knum = listofavailable[k];
              listofavailable.splice(k, 1);
              numgen = numgen.concat(knum);
              // seventh digit
              for (var b = 1; b >= 0; b--) {
                var bnum = listofavailable[b];
                listofavailable.splice(b, 1);
                numgen = numgen.concat(bnum);

                // eighth digit
                //add whatever else is left in listofavailable[0] to the string
                var jnum = listofavailable[0];
                numgen = numgen.concat(jnum);

                fullarray.push(numgen);
                //console.log(numgen);

                //revert list removals
                listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen.length - 2,1));

                //revert additions to the string
                numgen = numgen.substr(0,numgen.length-2);
              }// b loop
              listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen.length - 1));
              numgen = numgen.substr(0,numgen.length-1);
            }// k loop
            listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen.length - 1));
            numgen = numgen.substr(0,numgen.length-1);
          }// g loop
          listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen.length - 1));
          numgen = numgen.substr(0,numgen.length-1);
        }// c loop
        listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen.length - 1));
        numgen = numgen.substr(0,numgen.length-1);
      }// v loop
      listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen.length - 1));
      numgen = numgen.substr(0,numgen.length-1);
    } // i loop
    listofavailable.push(numgen.substr(numgen));
    numgen = "";
  } // a loop
};
generator();

console.log(fullarray.length);
console.log(fullarray);
```

**To explain what was wrong with the original code.**

You are getting an undefined on the second iteration of the b loop

```
              bnum = listofavailable[b];
```

this is because your function was emptying out the array of 7 available values, each time it splices out a value, leaving `listofavailable` as a single element array, `listofavailable[0] = "1"`.  However, when b iterates the second time it is trying to get the element `listofavailable[1]` which doesn't exist, hence `bnum = undefined`.  When trying to concatenate the `undefined` value to `numgen` this then makes `numgen = undefined` and breaks everything afterwards.

Additionally, the way you're trying to add to an array

```
fullarray = fullarray + numgen;
```

doesn't perform how you're intending, you're actually looking for the Array.prototype.push() function, so it would be

```
fullarray.push(numgen);
```

and using a reset value for the listofavailable is a good idea, but the way you've implemented it also won't work as

```
listofavailable = listofavailablereset;
```

doesn't copy the array elements from `listofavailablereset` into `listofavailable` but it just makes `listofavailable` reference the same array object, hence when you modify one, you're affecting the other.
Instead you can just copy your array over using `slice()` eg.

```
listofavailable = listofavailablereset.slice();
```

Note that `slice()` only creates a shallow copy, object references within each array will both point to the same object.

Check out the [Mozilla Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) pages for excellent javascript reference documentation.

Comment: I get all the fixes except the first one, could you explain it a little bit? If the array was empty, why would it have the value of 1?

Comment: Have fixed the code and tried to explain better what the issue was

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmm. I get what I was doing wrong, and I reallllly appreciate the answer. However, when I take the 0 and 5 out of there(supposed to be out, sorry for not stating that), it returns an array with a length of 35280, when I'm pretty sure it should be 8!, or 40320. Also, the individual values  have repeated digits, which is what I was trying to avoid with the splicing in the original one.

Comment: Thanks! :-) Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing by generating these permutations is isomorphic to enumerating all of the 8-digit base 8 numbers, so just do that:

```
var digits = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
var n, d, permutations = [], entry;

for (var i = 0, limit = parseInt("100000000", 8); i < limit; ++i) {
  entry = "";
  for (d = 0, n = i; d < digits.length; ++d) {
    entry = digits[n % 8] + entry;
    n = Math.floor(n / 8);
  }
  permutations.push(entry);
}
console.log(permutations);
```

Note that this will take a **long** time. Your browser (if you're doing it in a browser) will complain about a busy script.

Comment: Shouldn't the resulting array have a length of 8!, or 40320? This seems like a decently sized array for JS to handle. If not, why?

Comment: @LBMF_1 it depends - are you intending that the digits can be *re-used* - so, is 11111111 one of the values you want? If not, then this method I wrote won't work.

Comment: I was intending for the splice to remove the digit so it will not repeat. How much would this change your method?